# Jquery not post value if file select correct type

Tags: jquery

This is my code:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
    <div class="input">
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="attachment">
        <input type="file" name="attachement" id="attachement"/>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Send" id="btn_send" />
    </form>
```

and my script is:

```
<script>
function showFileSize() {
    var input, file;

        if (!window.FileReader) {
        bodyAppend("p", "The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
        return;
             }
        input = document.getElementById('attachement');
        file = input.files[0];
        var expi= file.name.toLowerCase().split(".");
        if((expi[1]=='jpg')||(expi[1]=='jpeg')||(expi[1]=='png')||(expi[1]=='gif'))
        {

            return true;
            }
        else {
                alert("Invalid file format");
                return false; 
            }
        }
```

and ajax post file to action.php

```
$('#btn_send').live('click', function() {
    var comments = $('textarea#comments').val();
    var imgVal = $('#attachement').val(); 

    if(comments=='')
    {
        alert("Enter comments");
        $('textarea#comments').focus();
        return false;
    }

    if(imgVal!='')
    {
    return showFileSize();  
    }

    var formData = new FormData($('#myform')[0]);
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "action.php",
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function() {

    }
    });
});
```

Whenever I selected not image file, it will show the alert "Invalid file format", but when I select correct file type, it not post the value?
How it fix?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is here:

```
if(imgVal!='')
{
return showFileSize();  
}
```

when the click event handler reaches this point, the return blocks the function before you reach the ajax request.

I think what you want if something like this:

```
$('#btn_send').live('click', function() {
   var comments = $('textarea#comments').val();
   var imgVal = $('#attachement').val(); 

   if(comments=='')
   {
       alert("Enter comments");
       $('textarea#comments').focus();
       return false;
   }

   if(imgVal!='')
   {
      if (showFileSize())
      {
         var formData = new FormData($('#myform')[0]);
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "action.php",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function() {

            }
         });
      }
   }
});
```

Otherwise you always return